# keras ImageDataGenerator Target data

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, deep-learning

According to [this](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) page we can build a generator using the `ImageDataGenerator` class (and `flow_from_directory` method) that we can pass to `model.fit_generator`
method in keras; like this:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'data/train',
    target_size=(150, 150),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='categorical')

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=2000,
    epochs=50)
```

But in the `flow_from_directory` method it only get the images for training from the directory and not the target labels because, while in normal `model.fit` method you pass the target data as a parameter, `model.fit_generator` accept only the generator of the training images; so where does it takes the expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `flow_from_dictionary` says that 'it should contain one subdirectory per class' this is because the name of the subdirectory will be the label of the class, so if you were to have pictures of dogs and cats in the appropriate labelled directories, the labels would be dogs and cats, this is most probably the thing you are looking for, i remember using the function like this, i cannot say anything if its changed

Comment: thank you very much for your answer; but I have another doubt: for the test generator we have to put the images all togheter in the directory or each one in its class folder like for the training data?

Comment: i think you woud put the images in one folder, not really sure about this, which function are you talking about exactly?

Comment: I was talking about flow_from_directory, when you have to evaluate the model on test data using a generator, you have to put all the data directly in the directory specified in the flow_from_directory method or you have to separate the data in the corresponding subdirectories (like what you do for the training data) ?

Comment: i am unsure about this, i think you just specify the `validation_split` variable in the `ImageDataGenerator` and it will split the data, you wouldn't need to load it separately

Comment: @ImtinanAzhar How could you load and augment images when pixels are already present in the Dataframe like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59596784/custom-imagedatagenerator-for-half-a-million-images-where-labels-and-pixels-ar)? Could you please answer it there?